# Fetching the latest entry for a job based on timestamp value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a scenario as below:

```
Message_No        Date                        JobNo   
ABC_872           09-06-2015  19:57:12       Job1
ABC_873           09-06-2015  20:57:12       Job1
ABC_874           09-06-2015  21:57:12       Job2
ABC_875           09-06-2015  22:57:12       Job2
```

I am trying to display something like this

```
Message_No        Date                        JobNo   
    ABC_873           09-06-2015  20:57:12       Job1
    ABC_875           09-06-2015  22:57:12       Job2
```

i.e the latest entry per job.

I have tried the below condition in where clause,

```
Message_No in (Select max(Message_No) from table group by jobno)
```

This gives me a result like this

```
Message_No        Date                        JobNo   
ABC_872           09-06-2015  19:57:12       Job1
ABC_874           09-06-2015  21:57:12       Job2
```

Message_NO is Varchar, is the usage of Max function correct?(I am using max on message number as the message no value increases by time)

Please guide

I even used the below query but ut gives all the rows,

```
create view viewname as
Select
msg.no as MessageNum,
msg.jobno as JobNumber,
msg.timedate as MessageCreateTime
from allmessages as msg inner join 
(
select no, max(timedate) as date1 from allmessages group by no
) as msg2 on msg.no=msg2.no and msg.timedate=msg2.date1
```

Answer (score 0):

`ROW_NUMBER` will do the trick:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY JobNo ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT *
FROM Cte
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.Message_No,t1.Date,t1.JobNo   from table as t1 inner join 
(
select Jobno, max(date) as date from table group by jobno
) as t2 on t1.jobno=t2.jobno and t1.date=t2.date
```

Comment: Hi, I used the below query and it gives all the values,
create view viewname as
Select
msg.no as MessageNum,
msg.jobno as JobNumber,
msg.timedate as MessageCreateTime
from allmessages as msg inner join 
(
select no, max(timedate) as date1 from allmessages group by no
) as msg2 on msg.no=msg2.no and msg.timedate=msg2.date1

Answer (score 0):

```
create view viewname as
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT msg.no as MessageNum
       ,msg.jobno as JobNumber
       ,msg.timedate as MessageCreateTime
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY msg.no ORDER BY msg.timedate DESC) as RNK
       from allmessages
 ) 
WHERE RNK=1
```